# Rendering different headers based on different pages in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react application, I need that the header should be rendered dynamically based on different pages.

I have a `<Layout/>`. Inside that I have `<Sidebar/>`, `<Header/>`, and `<Content/>`. My pages are wrapped by `<Content/>` as children.

I have a couple of pages that have their own needs. When I enter a particular page, a button and an input should appear in the `<Header/>` while only a button should appear on some other pages with different functionality. Those header inputs should be rendered as I enter that particular page.

Detailed information;

In my current code, every page needs different designs of the header. For instance; in A page there is a couple of buttons that depends on A page local or redux state. The same example for another page and they might need a search box which also depends on that particular page redux state.

How do I handle this so far?

When I enter a page, in a necessary lifecycle, I prepare a header by defining necessary JSX components (by passing the current state of the page) and with the help of a redux Action, I am keeping page-based things that are to be rendered in the header inside a redux state. Ever since the redux state updates, Header is also updated too and I get my page-specific header done.

I am looking for the best practice to accomplish this since keeping non-serializable content inside the redux state is not suggested and not a good practice.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.